# He made the decision that he "would/will" move to New York - which to use?

Tags: meaning, tense, appositives

**Example 1**

> "He made the decision that he would move to New York."

**Example 2**

> "He made the decision that he will move to New York."

If he made the decision but has not moved yet and will do so, which example to use?

Is this appositive clause?

Are both correct and convey the meaning I intended?

Answer (score -1):

He will move to New York is a definite statement that he has not yet moved but he will do so. He would move to New York is provisional. As in, He would move to New York if he had the money to do so.

Comment: Not necessarily, if speaking about events in the past. "He made the decision that he would move to New York, so he applied for a job and was settled there by the end of the year".